# Graphical rebus riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rhyme, rebus, science

I... I have some bad news. My computer broke. Yeah, really tragic. Luckily I have a backup computer, but there is a reason it is a backup. It was made a long time ago and... well, its completely rubbish to be honest.

I can't create any images so you'll have to make the rebus I want to give you. Obviously I can't just tell you, so I've hidden the three symbols in three verses.

**Solve them and then make and solve the rebus to find a common phrase**

1:

> Samuel Terence threw a ball
>   High above the ground
>   He was sad when it went up
>   But happy when it came down
>   His throw was straight
>   And his catch was sound

2:

> Susie Thompson drove her car
>   In fact she drove it twice
>   Each time she went at the same speed
>   But on the second time to be precise
>   She drove exactly twice as fast
>   But turn a corner to make things nice.

3:

> For the third Susie and Samuel joined forces
>   To make the phrase complete
>   Susie was kept original
>   And Samuel didn’t cheat
>   Their results combined were incredible
>   So show it on your sheet!

Oh, and one more thing... Names are important.

Hint:

> Massive clue in the title

Comment: Knowledge of a specific field in maths or science is required but I can't say which or I'll spoil the puzzle, however I have added a hint in the puzzle to what it is...

Comment: Uh... physics??

Comment: @greenturtle3141 well yes but a specific field in physics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some pestering by the OP,

> There are graphs (**graph**ical) ...

The first one

> It is a speed- time graph (Samuel Terence). So,the ball is thrown upwards. The sad thing indicates up means negative and happy indicates down means positive which doesn't really matter in speed. So, the graph first decreases as the speed decreases with increase in height of the ball as Kinetic Energy changes to potential energy(Assuming air resistance to be negligible). ANd after reaching the maximum height,the speed increases again. The graph [turns out to be a "v"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxs7U.jpg).

The 2nd one

> It is a speed-time graph (Susan Thompson). Same speed-means speed is constant and in a speed-time graph, constant speed means a line parallel to the time-axis. The "turn a corner" refers to rotating the graph by 90 degrees after which I get [two parallel lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaqCK.png)

The 3rd one

> It is a combination of both the above graphs. It is an inverted triangle with a line in it. [The alchemy symbol of Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh4Bg.png)

So, as Rubio finds out, the answer is

> Down to Earth. (One of my favorite fortnightly magazines as well)

Comment: Exam time helps :) +1

Comment: @Techidiot This was previous year's stuff....

Comment: @Sid- Combination of both.. N?

Comment: @Techidiot I first thought of "implies" but then, I saw "didn't cheat" and "N" looks a bit more promising..

Comment: Yeah. But not sure what VIN says? Why its an answer? Or OP just wanted to get the answer as 3 letters.

Comment: No, not "N".. Susie was kept original. So, equal sign remains. So, doesn't got rotated

Comment: @Sid Why are you saying the v-t plot is a 'v', rather than a '/' or '\'. The change of the ball's direction would change the sign of the velocity, not the slope. The slope of the v-t line is the acceleration, which does not change.

Comment: It is a speed-time graph and not velocity-time. The graph has the name of the axis wrong.

Comment: So the rebus is:   **V || **

Answer (score 3):

Taking a stab at the final solution.

## V ||

means

> $\begin{array}{cc}\mathbf V&\mathbf{Down}\\\mathbf{||}&\mathbf{to}\\\mathbf{ }&\mathbf{Earth}\end{array}$

Oh, and I'm blatantly hopping in at the last minute after [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45566/30633) did **all** the heavy lifting on this solution with OP in Sphinx's Lair.  Give him all the up-votes, please!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer -(Not close)

For first part

> It seems like graViTy(Victor Terence) which gives "g'

For second part

> It seems like acceleration=(vf-vi)/t or Δv/t  or distance=Speed * Time(Susie Thomposon) which gives "a"

For third part

> It seems like f(force)=mass(scalar)*acceleration(vector) which gives "f"

Comment: Sorry not even close

Comment: You are right with the names meaning somethng but they don't mean that

Comment: Are they a part of some extensive physics like quantum, emw etc? If thats the case, I am not literal enough :D

Comment: Oh no no, I have even done GCSE Science yet if that helps with the level of science knowledge required. Read the hint - can't believe no ones noticed it yet

Comment: Is it graph theory? Again, I am weak with that :(

Comment: To do with graphs but I don't know what graph theory is...

Comment: I thought by symbols you meant symbols used in physics/maths. Didn't knew the symbols can be graphs as well